# send feedback to the browser when still processing data in the php server

Tags: php, mysql

hello in my code i send a bunch of data to the server with the json from the javascript,in the server i will store this data to the mysql database,because i'am going to store the data one rows at a time i want to make the client aware of the progress made in the server side,the code is

```
for($j=0 ; $j < $number_rows; ++$j){
    $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name(column_name)VALUES('value')");
    if(!$result)
        //here i want to send the browser that the $j rows is saved and 
        //that for every iteration
    }
```

so is that possible or the server wouldn't be able to send the data until the script is all terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) in the mean time, although it doesn't always work.

The detailed description of caveats can be found on the documentation page I linked before. In short, `flush` will try to send (flush) all current output to the browser, but other process, like PHP output buffering, Apache compression layers, and even buffering by the browser itself may cause the output to not appear in the browser immediately.

Comment: think's it really represent my case that's exactly what i wanted,make the echo and then flush() and then the browser will receive in every time the progress made before the loop will end.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are not aware of $.ajax() method of jquery.
It allows you to send the data to the server and keep the control in the browser.

You can use it like this:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'insert-data.php',
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        // setting a timeout
        $('.sending').addClass('Sending data...');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data==1) {
            $('.sending').html('Saved data successfully.');
        } else {
            $('.sending').html('Oops..! Something went wrong!!!');
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems you misunderstood the question. It's about showing progress while saving.

Comment: yes you are right because i send the entire data at once to the server,and it's up to the server to fetch the row and save it to the database the case above don't apply to me.think's for the reply